# Extra Page in the end : Adobe Live Cycle Designer

Tags: css

When I select the option for "Go to the Next Page", an extra page is added to the Pdf, Which is not acceptable by the customer.

The first page contains dynamic growing rows, basically the data in the first page will be filled in run time. So, we select the option to flow to the next page , if there is more data.
But, in that case an extra empty  page is added , even if the data is not flowing to the next page.

Please find the option that I selected.
Let me know how can I solve this issue.
Please find the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your pagination "After" setting to "Continue Filling Parent". The pagination settings here refer to Master Pages not normal pages.